# How do I store date from a list of params in grails?

Tags: grails, date, groovy

I tried to create a service (code below). It gets the list of params passed from the controller, and iterates through the params and saves it. Now I keep getting this error:

```
    Error 500: Executing action [save] of controller [controller.EmploymentHistoryController] caused exception: Runtime error executing action
Servlet: grails
URI: /hrapp/grails/employmentHistory/save.dispatch
Exception Message: No signature of method: static service.EmploymentHistoryService.saveEmploymentHistory() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap) values: [[position:ksfdj, startDate:Wed Feb 22 00:00:00 PHT 2012, ...]] Possible solutions: saveEmploymentHistory(java.lang.Object) 
Caused by: No signature of method: static service.EmploymentHistoryService.saveEmploymentHistory() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap) values: [[position:ksfdj, startDate:Wed Feb 22 00:00:00 PHT 2012, ...]] Possible solutions: saveEmploymentHistory(java.lang.Object)
```

here is my code:

```
def saveEmploymentHistory(params){
    
    params.company = [params.company].flatten()
    params.position = [params.position].flatten()
    params.responsibilities = [params.responsibilities].flatten()
    params.startDate = [params.startDate].flatten()
    params.endDate = [params.endDate].flatten()
    params.employee = [params.employee].flatten()
    
    params.company.eachWithIndex{ company, i ->
        def employmentHistory = new EmploymentHistory()
        
        employmentHistory.employee = params.employee[i]
        employmentHistory.company = company
        employmentHistory.position = params.position[i]
        employmentHistory.responsibilities = params.responsibility[i] 
        
        def tempStartDate = "${params.startDate_year[i]}/${params.startDate_month[i]}/${params.startDate_day[i]}"
        employmentHistory.startDate = new Date(tempStartDate)
            
        def tempEndDate = "${params.endDate_year[i]}/${params.endDate_month[i]}/${params.endDate_day[i]}"
        employmentHistory.endDate = new Date(tempEndDate)
        
        employmentHistory.save(flush:true)
    }
    
    

}
```

I bet the error comes from the date thingy. I tried several solutions found [here](http://grails.org/FAQ#Q:%20How%20do%20I%20get%20the%20date%20from%20a%20form%20submission?) but to no avail. Also tried doing the code below, but still gets the same error...

```
employmentHistory.endDate = new Date(params.endDate[i])
employmentHistory.startDate = new Date(params.startDate[i])
```

Another one I tried, but still a failure:

```
    employmentHistory.endDate = params.endDate[i]
    employmentHistory.startDate = params.startDate[i]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this properly? I'm not very familiar with groovy. :(
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you call this `saveEmploymentHistory` from controller?

Comment: This is how I call it..EmploymentHistoryService.saveEmploymentHistory(params) I forgot to add the classname above... but that's not the problem.

Comment: So, you're calling it as a `static` but it doesn't `static`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're trying to call this service method as static method (like `EmploymentHistoryService.saveEmploymentHistory()`), but really need an instance method. See [Class Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

To make this, you need to define service field (it will be wired automatically by grails), in head of your controller:

```
class EmploymentHistoryController {

   def employmentHistoryService

}
```

and then call it as:

```
def save() {

    employmentHistoryService.saveEmploymentHistory(params)

}
```

Or you can also make your service method as `static`, but at this case you don't really need a service, it can be any class.